# Syntax highlighter failing for specific code block

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, specific-answer

Something in the following JavaSript code block seems to be confusing the syntax highlitgher:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstr); //parse the JSON to a JS object
var ids = [];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

   //loop over the array and if the id is defined add it
   if(typeof data[i].id !== "undefined"){
       ids.push(data[i].id);
   }
}
```

It's getting rendered like this:

[image]

The problem persists even after manually forcing the language with `<!-- language: lang-js-->`. It's working just fine for other answers to the same question.

What's wrong? Is it something on the code, or an issue with the highlighter script? The answer in question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386563/825789).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include a space in the language hint:

```
<!-- language:lang-js -->
```

instead of:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

I fixed that for you.

The post had several conflicting tags (mainly ruby vs. javascript) so the hint was required to prevent the prettifier from making the wrong guess.

Comment: Oh god. Stupid me. Sorry.

Comment: @bfavaretto: NP, don't feel sorry! You tried to help, and it was an easy mistake to make. :-) If you stop editing and wait 5 seconds, the prettifier is re-applied, so you can see if your fix worked in the preview window.

Comment: Thanks. I *think* I tried with the space earlier, and the preview was still showing the broken highlighting. But I probably was trying stuff too fast.